# Different View Controllers for one View objective C

Tags: ios, containers, viewcontroller

In my app I have a complicated View which contains:
A corePlot graph
A Collection View (controlled by Core Data)
and some other Views, (controlled by Core Data different request)
The items in the collection view, can be copy-dragged out to the Core Plot.
I think it would be nicer and easier to have several view Controllers:
one controller for the Core Plot, one for The collection view and so on. Because if I have only one view controller to control all of these items, it will be a huge file containing a lot of code and not well structured.
Could I use Container for this problem? or is it better to stick with the huge ViewController file? Or is there another solution? If yes can this solution be done in the storyboard?

Answer (score 3):

The [Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH18-SW6) seems perfect for what you want:

All the steps are listed in the link above, but to be short:
- you add the child view controller to the container with `[self addChildViewController:childVC]`
- then you set the view of the container `[self.view addSubview:childVC.view]`
- and then tell the child view controller that it is set in the container with `[childVC didMoveToParentViewController:self]`

Then if you want to switch to a new child view controller:
- Call `[self addChildViewController:newVC]` and `[source willMoveToParentViewController:nil]`, so the container know that you are going to switch the child view controller.
- then do the transition with:

```
[self transitionFromViewController:oldVC toViewController:newVC  
                          duration:/*you duration*/ 
                           options:/*your options*/ 
                        animations:/*your animations*/   
                        completion:/*your completion*/]
```

- and at the end  call `[oldVC removeFromParentViewController]` and `[newVC didMoveToParentViewController:self]` to let the container know that the switch is done.

Hope that helps.

Comment: nice one and useful too

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do now... but I cannot get the container to show on my main View.. I have a container, that seques to a collection View in my storyboard. I added the IBAction for the container to the main controller. I also set the containers view to its specific Collection view controller in the storyboard. Where should I call addChildViewController ? This can only be called on a ViewController, not on the container, which is a view. So how to call addChildViewController on a container

Comment: Can this be done using the view container in the storyboard? Is this the same thing, than what "aMother" proposed?

Comment: Yes this is possible, and it's the same thing that @aMother proposed. Even if Apple only explain how to do it by code, you can find some [tutorials](http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers) which explain everything you need.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried it now in simpler application and it worked, which means there was something else not working before.

Answer (score 1):

You can have different view controllers for your views. But, you have to try this hack since you want to present the content of all view controllers at the same time on a single scene.
Container view controllers are the view controllers which present the content of their children view controller. But, a container view presents only one child at a time. So, you have to create a view controller and add as many container views as many you want view controllers. I have attached a snapshot .[image: snapshot]

Hope this helps!

Steps to achieve this in a story board:
1) In the IB choose a view controller.
2) Add **Container Views** from IB to view hierarchy of view controller.
3) You can change the child of container view by simply deleting it and connecting your desired view controller.
4) Both the children of both container views are presented without any code in a storyboard.

For initialization of your view controllers and delegation b/w the I highly recommend you to review the sample codes in  [View Controller Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)

Comment: Thank you, do I need to connect the containers To the Main View controller? i did that (I have an IBOutlet for my Containers)... but what do I do afterwards... my views do not get displayed

Comment: Hope this helps now. Please do review that guide once. Also, accept this answer if it helps you

Comment: I am glad it helped you. Also, please accept this answer by clicking the right sign below +1 and -1 btns. Also, feel free to +1. It's the way of saying thanks on stackoverflow.